# setInterval calls in functional components using hooks in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In a ReactJs app, `setInterval` is being used in the demo below. Currently, it waits for 10 seconds even at inital load, instead, it should call immediately then after 10 second it should call again. How can i achieve this?

```js
const callApiAfterOneSec = async () => {
    await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
          .then(res => {
              setLoading(false);
              setPost(res.data);
          })
          .catch(err => {
              setLoading(false);
              console.log(err);
          });
};

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(callApiAfterOneSec, 10000);
    return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
    };
}, [post]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add another `useEffect()`, fired only once:

```
useEffect(() => {
  callApiAfterOneSec();
}, []);
```

Comment: What about interval ? need to call this api every 10 second

Comment: Let me clear my question it should invoke callApiAfterOneSec immediately and after 10 second interval will call it

Comment: use `useEffect` twice, I wrote  "add another", not replace ;)

Comment: Well i would like know is this good practice because if I updated value either from DB or via input field it will initialise old value then new one doesn't it ?

Comment: What do you mean? You're asking DB for current data every 10 seconds ... to keep view up to date ... no matter how many changes was, where came from ... view can have old data for 10 sec, it's acceptable? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this as class component

```
class App extends React.Component {

      interval;
      constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
          data: {}
        }
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.loadData();
        this.interval = setInterval(this.loadData, 5000);
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        clearTimeout(this.interval);
      }

      async loadData() {
        try {
          const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
          await res.json().then(res => {

            this.setState({
              data: res
            })
          })
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>UserId : {this.state.data.userId}</li>
              <li>Title : {this.state.data.title}</li>
              <li>Body : {this.state.data.body}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }

    }
    render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

As @xadm mention you can useEffect two times as per requirement simple fix

```
useEffect(() => {
  callApiAfterOneSec();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hack that might solve you problem.

```
const [rendered, setRendered] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  let interval = null;
  if(rendered) interval =  setInterval(callApiAfterOneSec, 10000)
  setRendered(true);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
}, [post, rendered])
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: you can not reassign the const interval that's fine we can change the variable but even though you are setting setRendered post api call that will not work i guess

Comment: It will work because for the first time API call will not be made because of `if` condition. You should try this once and if there is any error let me know.

Comment: JUST tried nothing works it is still waiting 10 second for first load